# Is privacy and data security compromised with Record Linkage?

Tags: security, privacy, record-linkage

I was in my Information Systems class when there was a discussion about Record Linkage and the question about the **security and privacy** of the data when we used this process. My teacher just said that this is a concern when this method is used and did not know or did not want to exemplify.

As it is a subject that interests me I would like to know if someone who studies or works with this would know to me if there is in fact this concern with the privacy and data security when Record Linkage is used with some purpose and if this has some connection with industrial secret and etc. I'm no expert on the subject but I would like to understand, if anyone can recommend me some reading including scientific articles on this would already be of great help too.

Comment: If you're still interested, I work in this corner of the field--linking records with a high degree of privacy concern.